# Dispatching priority of waiting jobs

Tags: scheduler, sungridengine

I am investigating scheduling issues on gridengine (6.2u5) and I am puzzled by the scheduling priority of waiting tasks. When I run qstat I can see in the second column (prior) the priority of running jobs (they all have positive values there) but all the waiting jobs have zeroes in that field so I am unable to check which waiting job actually has the higher priority for the next scheduling. Does it depend on configuration or is it expected to have zeroes for jobs in "qw" state? Is there any way to show computed priority values for jobs which did not get dispatched yet?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs will typically only have a priority of 0.0000 if they are not being considered for scheduling.

Situations where this may arise are: jobs in `hqw` state, or array tasks where the currently running jobs matches the `tc` value.

Comment: In my case all jobs in qw state (so not on hold) have 0 prio. What is the tc value by the way?

Comment: tc value is the task concurrency value, which defines how many tasks in an array can run at once. it's also possible that your HPC admin has added some default settings which are applied to every job that are affecting this. typically i would expect most queueing jobs to get a priority value